# Taxonomy URL incorrectly translated

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

On a multilingual site (source language: English) I have a view that displays a few product categories. The categories are represented by Taxonomy terms. If I display the (translated) category names linking to the respective category overview page, everything works perfectly: The links are being translated, too.

But when I introduce a category image (an extra field in our category Taxonomy type) the generated image link will never be translated. This means: My view renders the category name as link in the *Interface text language selected for page* (e.g. http://example.com/de/tastatur/xy-123) and the category image as link in English (e.g. http://example.com/en/keyboard/xy-123). I even have tried to set the *Rendering language* parameter to German, but the image link is always being rendered in English.

Is this a bug, or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, but I hope someone will come up with a better solution.

If I include the Term ID as a hidden field …

[image: View Dialogue: FIELDS]

… it is possible to rewrite the category image with a link generated by the router:

[image: View FIELDS Dialogue: Category Image]

This works, but we are missing the *hreflang* attribute in the link, and the *alt* attribute of the category image is still English only.